# "Dr. sqlite3_bind_text" and "Mr. sqlite3_column_text" Mystery

Tags: c++, sqlite

Why `sqlite3_column_text` returns `unsigned char *`,
But `sqlite3_bind_text` takes `const char *`.


This may be interested when you are going to store an array of bytes in a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store some *array of bytes* (not null terminated strings) you should use [sqlite3_bind_blob](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) instead of `sqlite3_bind_text` (which wants a text, i.e. a null-terminated string).

If you know that you are handling null-terminated strings, use `sqlite3_bind_text`, perhaps with a cast to `(const char*)`; in C casts don't change any data at runtime (except for numerical conversion to or from floating points or larger or smaller integral types), they are just changing the compile-time type (at least for pointer types on common systems).

<sup>(In the previous century, some weird machines -e.g. Cray1- had different pointer type sizes, e.g. `char*` pointers did not have the same number of bits that `int*` pointers).</sup>

Comment: What if we want to store UTF8 string witch is stored in unsigned char*?

Comment: Does not the cast change the data? If not this is the answer!

Comment: @Amir casting pointer to another pointer type only changes how it will be dereferenced, address remains the same. Be careful though, compiler wouldn't check what you do (in most cases, it just can't).

Comment: The question asks *why* the input and output types are different. How does this answer address that?